Has the Catholic Church issued standing instructions on caring for clergymen with psychological disorder?
In separate startling incidents, two Parish Priests of Roman Catholic Church of India reportedly gave up their life recently after having undergone treatment for psychological condition. In many parishes, the priests lead isolated life and are prone to suicidal tendency in case they have psychological disorder. Such incidences could have been avoided if the priests were withdrawn from the parish and kept in community life under observation.
My question is: Has the Catholic Church issued any standing instructions to Bishops in order to stave off such unfortunate incidents?

why does the parish keep the priest isolated in the first place?  Don't they have constant contact with the parish community?  In US/Canada parishes priests are invited to social functions, even to eat out at restaurants with groups of parish members after mass.  And if some parish members complain, the priest could have pointed to Jesus saying that He did the same thing, esp. since Catholic priests acts in persona christi even if officially only in performing the  sacraments.

I am immediately reminded of Diary of a Country Priest, which although fictional, lays out a plausible scenario for the time: a young priest in a remote rural parish in Northern France dealing with hostile parishioners, starting to become convinced that God has abandoned him. It is outside my expertise, but a cursory reading of recent studies suggests that up to 8% of Catholic parish priests suffer from severe depression and anxiety. In light of this, this question "Does the Catholic Church follow a prescribed course of action if it becomes aware of it?" seems valid, not sure why the DV.

@GratefulDisciple while I've never heard of anyone complaining about the parish priest being included in various social functions of a parish, that alone doesn't solve the problems highlighted in the question. Although Americans may blur or downplay the distinctions between laypeople and clergy, they are still there. I suspect that at least some of the isolation reported above is due to that.
